# How to prevent redundant lookups when joining entity relationships?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm getting up to speed with Symfony 2 and Doctrine and having difficulties with the number of unnecessary database lookups being performed to hydrate with joined entities.

After performing a joined query with a child object, the child is automatically pulling its other mappings from the database. It's doing this despite that I'm not attempting to access any of its properties. It's as if they're being accessed inside the `find` query.

My example looks like the below - There are entities called `Person` and `Building` that both join an entity called `Place`:

```
class Person {
    /**
     * Where this person lives
     * @var Place $Home
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Place", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="Resident" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="place_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $Home;
}

class Building {

    /**
     * Where this building stands
     * @var Place $Site
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Place", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="Landmark" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="place_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $Site;
}

class Place {
    /**
     * Reverse mapping
     * @var Person $Resident
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="Home")
     */   
    private $Resident;

    /**
     * Reverse mapping
     * @var Building $Landmark
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Building", mappedBy="Site")
     */   
    private $Landmark;
}
```

My Person repository join looks like this:

```
/**
 * @override
 * @return Person
 */
public function find( $id ){
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p, h
            FROM MyBundle:Person p
            JOIN p.Home h
            WHERE p.id = :id'
        )->setParameter('id', $id);
    return $query->getSingleResult();
}
```

How can I prevent the Place fetching its Building relationship separately during the `find` operation? Is there something I can pass into the Query instance to stop this?

Comment: I've uploaded an example bundle. If nobody can replicate this error then there must be something wrong with my setup. http://static.timwhitlock.info/MyExampleBundle.tar.gz

Comment: I'm able to prevent the auto-fetching by setting this on the query: 

`$query->setHint( Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true );`
Problem is it kills lazy loading when I actually do want it.

Answer (score -1):

add `fetch` option to your mapping.

Like so:

> class Place {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Reverse mapping
>  * @var Person
>  * 
>  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="Home", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
>  */   
> private $Resident;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: not working for me, I'm afraid. Lazy should be enough anyway. There's something about my initial join that is preventing laziness.

Comment: only reason for this not to work is if you have `$place->getResident()` call somewhere

Comment: this is what I thought, but I don't.

Comment: There's no reason for doctrine to pull additional data if mapping is defined as lazy, doctrine will just ignore it **unless data is explicitly requested**. Cache, sneaky service, twig extension, access in templates, access in forms, custom repository not loaded and `->find` goes to default. Don't assume you have an edge case, re-check 100 times first.

Comment: Fair comment. I've simplified my code into an example bundle and uploaded. I can still replicate the extra query in this and have no clue where there could be a reference to Place::Resident, I've even excluded a Resident getter method. http://static.timwhitlock.info/MyExampleBundle.tar.gz